# :not() is not ignoring class in list-items with links

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to use `:not()` to ignore the `.current` class in the first list item.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a</li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li a:not(.current){color:red}
```

I can't get the `:not()` to ignore the `.current` class.

I have also tried:

```
 ul li a:not(.current a){color:red}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hg6o9dkb/)

Comment: Your class is on the `li` not the `a`, so try `ul li:not(.current) a { color: red; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the [**`:not`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) applies to element in use, so apply to `li` which  is using `current` in this case

plus, not sure if was a typo, but in your second `li`, the `a` was missing a `<` in closing tag

```css
ul li:not(.current) a {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class is on the li element in your html so:

```
ul li:not(.current) a { color: red; }
```

should work.